# Centering the image

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

How should i calculate the left offset to center align the image inside the container?

[image]

**Example**

```
container width: 190mm
image width: 63,5 mm
left offset: ?
```

Comment: Is this really math ?

Comment: It's certainly not calculus...

Comment: @ZevChonoles Sorry im not very familiar with math expressions, but it is maths, why wouldnt it be?

Comment: @J.W.Perry Yes this certainly is the first part, as i figured out before, but the problem is the width of image. If it is too long it does not look centered anymore since 0,0 coordinates of image start in center, but image's width itself reaches to the right. I guess i should move image to left after using your formula but dont know for what value.

Comment: Left offset $={container width\over 2}-{image width\over 2}$.

Comment: @abiessu Works great, thanks. I tried with that formula before but it didnt work out because i made a mistake and used wrong container width. Write this as answer if you want me to accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When centering one box inside another, use the difference of the widths (or heights) divided by $2$ as the position of the left (or top) edge of the inner box relative to the left (or top) edge of the outer box.  In particular, let $a$ be the left edge coordinate of the inner box (the image in this case), and let $b$ be the outer box width, and $c$ be the inner box width.  Then

$$a={b\over 2}-{c\over 2}={b-c\over 2}$$

Will set the position of the inner box to be centered horizontally within the outer box.  Note that centering vertically will use a matching formula involving the heights of the two objects.